# How to print images in vb6

Tags: vb6

am having tiff images(front and rear images) in vb6 application. I am saving the tiff images to my local folder from fim and rim files and from there i am trying to print images.

Initially i tried to load the images to picturecox and tried to print the images, but tiff images are not able to print in this way. i am getting an error as invalid Picture. 
.bmp and .jpg are working fine.

```
If pblnFlipped Then
        Set frmnewimage.img.Picture = Nothing
        frmnewimage.img.Picture = LoadPicture(mstrRearTiffImageFile)
        Else
        Set frmnewimage.img.Picture = Nothing
        frmnewimage.img.Picture = LoadPicture(mstrFrontTiffImageFile)
        End If
        Printer.PaintPicture frmnewimage.img.Picture, 100, 100
        Printer.EndDoc
```

so i am saving the picture to my local. but i am not under standing how to print images directly from the saved images. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance!!!!

What I have tried:

```
If pblnFlipped Then
       Printer.PaintPicture mstrRearTiffImageFile, 10, 10
       Else
       Printer.PaintPicture mstrFrontTiffImageFile, 10, 10
       End If
       Printer.EndDoc
```

mstrRearTiffImageFile and mstrFrontTiffImageFile are strings(rear image and front image). it consist of images which i need to print. based upon the image type (pblnFlipped) i need print images.

Comment: here is an example using freeimage.dll: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?554191-Convert-Images-upto-31-Formats-using-FreeImage-dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supported file formats for the built-in VB6 [image control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa242027%28v=vs.60%29#supported-graphic-formats) as well as the [Picture Box control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa263544%28v%3Dvs.60%29#supported-graphic-formats) don't include support for TIFF files.

You'll need to either convert the files to a supported image format before loading them into VB6, or create or find some other custom control that supports the TIFF format.

I don't know why you're doing new development in VB6, but you may find it easier to accomplish your goals using some other platform that has more extensive graphics support, and then call it from whatever VB code you're maintaining.